# Ravendb query order by value

Tags: java, ravendb

I have objects with fields `score` and `id`. I need to get some amount of this objecs from `from` to `from + count`, which ordering by field `score` in descending order. Inside each equals range I need to get object with specific value of `id` on top of this range if it exist.

Example:

```
 1. score = 10, id = 5
 2. score = 20, id = 6
 3. score = 20, id = 7
 4. score = 20, id = 8
 5. score = 30, id = 9
```

Specific value `id` = 7, `from` = 0, `count` = 2

Expected result:

```
 1. score = 30, id = 9
 2. score = 20, id = 7  <--- my specific value on top of equal range, where score = 20
```

I write simple query:

```
final List<SomeClass> players = session.query(SomeClass.class, SomeIndexClass.class)
            .orderByDescending("score", OrderingType.LONG)
            .skip(from)
            .take(count)
            .toList();
```

But this does not take into account the conditions with specific value `id`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this `id` field indexed in your index, then you can add a `whereGreaterThan` condition in your query, to **filter** for those id's that are greater than '7'

So query would be something like:

```
final List<SomeClass> players = session.query(SomeClass.class, SomeIndexClass.class)
            .whereGreaterThan("id", 7)
            .orderByDescending("score", OrderingType.LONG)
            .skip(from)
            .take(count)
            .toList();
```

See documentation link: 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/java/indexes/querying/filtering#where---numeric-property

Is `id` the document id ?
because then it doesn't have to be indexed, should work w/ just adding the 'where' condition to the query.
See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/java/indexes/querying/basics#example-ii---filtering

Btw, check out the **code samples** in https://demo.ravendb.net/ 
In each sample, click the 'Java' tab to see **sample Java code**.